# Display a PDF in a webview

Tags: pdf, google-chrome-app

I want to display a pdf in a webview, but the chrome pdf plugin only shows a blank/grey rectangel.

Am I missing a permission in my manifest.json?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like that if the width of the webview is set to a high value (in my case I set it to 10000) the pdf renders only a grey rectangel. Resetting the width to a more sane value brings back the pdf.

Comment: In your original attempt, have you tried scrolling to the middle of the webview? Is it possible that you PDF was centered there, hidden out of the view initially?

Comment: Just tried to scroll, but scrolling is not possible.